# Overlay on table cell on hover of first cell

Tags: html, css, hover, css-tables

I have create a table listing. When user hover the first cell that is with 3 dots **Edit** and **Delete** option are displayed and below that there is a transparent background.

Everything is fine when content is in single line.

Issue is when there is more content. The height of overlay does not adjust. I have tried `top: 0; bottom: 0; height: 100%` to the `.action` it covers the whole table.

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc
}
.tHead,
.tRow {
  display: table-row;
  position: relative;
}
.tCell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.tHead .tCell {
  background: #ccc;
}
.tRow:hover .tCell {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-color: #000;
}
.tRow:hover + .tRow .tCell {
  border-color: #000;
}
.tRow .tCell:first-child {
  width: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1
}
.menu {
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 3px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.menu:before,
.menu:after {
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 3px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  top: -6px;
}
.menu:before {
  top: -12px;
}
.actions {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -19px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 28px;
}
.tCell:hover .menu:before,
.tCell:hover .menu:after,
.tCell:hover .menu {
  background: #000
}
.tCell:hover .actions {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tHead">
    <div class="tCell"></div>
    <div class="tCell">Name</div>
    <div class="tCell">Age</div>
    <div class="tCell">Gender</div>
    <div class="tCell">Job Profile</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tRow">
    <div class="tCell"><span class="menu"></span><span class="actions">
      <a href="#">Edit</a> |
      <a href="#">Delete</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="tCell">Kelly</div>
    <div class="tCell">28</div>
    <div class="tCell">Female</div>
    <div class="tCell">Web Developer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tRow hovered">
    <div class="tCell"><span class="menu"></span>
      <span class="actions">
      <a href="#">Edit</a> |
      <a href="#">Delete</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="tCell">Jack

    </div>
    <div class="tCell">32</div>
    <div class="tCell">Male</div>
    <div class="tCell">Java Developer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tRow">
    <div class="tCell"><span class="menu"></span><span class="actions">
      <a href="#">Edit</a> |
      <a href="#">Delete</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="tCell">
      Janaya
    </div>
    <div class="tCell">26</div>
    <div class="tCell">Female</div>
    <div class="tCell">.Net Developer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tRow ">
    <div class="tCell"><span class="menu"></span><span class="actions">
      <a href="#">Edit</a> |
      <a href="#">Delete</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="tCell">Jim</div>
    <div class="tCell">24</div>
    <div class="tCell">Male</div>
    <div class="tCell">Full Stack Developer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps you.

Use `:before` for the overlay on the cell and target the cells using `~` operator. I had same requirement. This is how I handled it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.tHead,
.tRow {
  display: table-row;
  position: relative;
}
.tCell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative
}
.tRow:last-child .tCell {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.tHead .tCell {
  background: #ccc;
}
.tRow:hover .tCell {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-color: #000;
}
.tRow .tCell:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
.tRow:hover + .tRow .tCell {
  border-color: #000;
}
.tRow .tCell:first-child {
  width: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1
}
.menu {
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 3px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.menu:before,
.menu:after {
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 3px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  top: -6px;
}
.menu:before {
  top: -12px;
}
.actions {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 4;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -19px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 28px;
}
.tCell:hover .menu:before,
.tCell:hover .menu:after,
.tCell:hover .menu {
  background: #000
}
.tCell:hover .actions {
  display: block
}
.tRow:hover .tCell:first-child:hover:before,
.tRow:hover .tCell:first-child:hover ~ .tCell:before {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tHead">
    <div class="tCell"></div>
    <div class="tCell">Name</div>
    <div class="tCell">Age</div>
    <div class="tCell">Gender</div>
    <div class="tCell">Job Profile</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tRow">
    <div class="tCell"><span class="menu"></span><span class="actions">
      <a href="#">Edit</a> |
      <a href="#">Delete</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="tCell">Kelly</div>
    <div class="tCell">28</div>
    <div class="tCell">Female</div>
    <div class="tCell">Web Developer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tRow hovered">
    <div class="tCell"><span class="menu"></span>
      <span class="actions">
      <a href="#">Edit</a> |
      <a href="#">Delete</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="tCell">Jack

    </div>
    <div class="tCell">32</div>
    <div class="tCell">Male</div>
    <div class="tCell">Java Developer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tRow">
    <div class="tCell"><span class="menu"></span><span class="actions">
      <a href="#">Edit</a> |
      <a href="#">Delete</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="tCell">
      Janaya
    </div>
    <div class="tCell">26</div>
    <div class="tCell">Female</div>
    <div class="tCell">.Net Developer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tRow ">
    <div class="tCell"><span class="menu"></span><span class="actions">
      <a href="#">Edit</a> |
      <a href="#">Delete</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="tCell">Jim</div>
    <div class="tCell">24</div>
    <div class="tCell">Male</div>
    <div class="tCell">Full Stack Developer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great...Thanks @Tushar

Answer (score 0):

@Tushar .. I noticed that the bottom line of the table, the div border never gets updated on the hover.. [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/27wvhvua/6/)

`.tCell:hover .menu:before,
 .tCell:hover .menu:after,
 .tCell:hover .menu {
  background: #000;
}`

Comment: I have updated the answer. Changed the bottom border from table to .tRow:last-child. It works now.

Comment: @Tushar, I have been playing with this, and your solution is amazing..  I am new to css3 and it's nuances.. But I am always trying to learn more!!  I am used to <TABLE> functionality under CSS, and now I am trying to figure out how to implement some of the other styling that I am used to under a <DIV> table model, such as changing the colours of alternating rows, .tRow:nth-child() didn't work for me, and I haven't even tried to ellipse long <DIV> Cells..  Any further pointers or links to a good div table tutorial would be much appreciated!!

Comment: And of coarse once I ask the question, the correct answer comes to me..   .tRow:nth-child(odd) .tCell {
   background-color: #FCDFEB;
  } works great when selects the children which are where all of the actual work and formatting are being done.. :)